# How to read Chinese from Clipboard correctly in R?

Tags: r, clipboard

In R (and Windows system), how to read Chinese correctly from the clipboard?

For example, I first copy `测试` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Then, in R, I used

```
 o = readClipboard()
```

However, what `o` returns is `??`.

I wonder what I should do to correctly read Chinese from the clipboard in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the format argument. This worked for me.

```
o = readClipboard(format=13)
Encoding(o) = "UTF-8"
cat(o, "\n")
发动机测谎报告
```